# interface reference to its implemented object in php

Tags: php, interface

I'm trying to point a interface reference to its implemented object in PHP.
Here's my try

Here's the class:

```
class Account implements FDInterface
{
    public $bal;
    public function Account() 
    {
        $bal = 0;
        echo 'Account created with balance '.$bal;
    }

    public function getFDInterest()
    {
        echo '</br> Interest Rate is 9.85';
    }
}
```

The interface:

```
interface FDInterface 
{
    public function getFDInterest();
}
```

And the real problem here in `Index.php`

```
FDInterface fdAcc = new Account();   // this is line 1
$fdAcc->getFDInterest();
```

Output I get is

> syntax error, unexpected T_STRING Index.php on line 1

Comment: I'm afraid you have mistaken PHP for some other language. Line 1 is simply invalid syntactically and in addition does not make logical sense.

Comment: @Jon I am a java/Objective-C developer, was trying the same syntax here. I hope this is syntactically correct in Java. Anyhow I got the answer below.

Comment: Oh, I see. You didn't bother to look up PHP syntax because you figured someone else would tell you. Forgive me for thinking that before trying to write code one would actually take a look at the manual. Judging from the deprecated form of writing a constructor that you also "ported" from Java you 're going to be asking lots of questions like this. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `FDInterface fdAcc = new Account();`. Data type in this case interface you can use only as parameter in function as:

```
function callSometing(FDInterface $fdAcc) {
     $fdAcc->something();
}
```

In your case, correct and functional code is:

```
$fdAcc = new Account();
```